# Eclipse adt cannot find my Samsung GT-S7562

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

I connected my samsung GT-S7562 with a usb cable and started developing an android application. I can't find the device at the AVD manager. What could it be wrong?

Comment: install the samsug drivers

Comment: Drivers com with KIES. http://www.samsung.com/mx/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Juliatzin del Toro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1956558/juliatzin-del-toro) said in his comment. The installation of [KIES](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/) is the solution

Answer (score 0):

You have to install Google USB Driver for the phone, so you can use adb to debug.

Use this one: http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html